# ¿Donde se encuentra mi error al intentar mostrar esta gràfica con Chart.js?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, chart.js

Dentro de mi proyecto Laravel estoy implementando la librería chart.js tratando de visualizar un gráfico de barras.
**El cual debería de mostrar todas las órdenes de trabajo en estado terminado que se asignaron a los usuarios con el rol de operario.**

Al querer graficar, simplemente **no se visualiza ningún dato, es un grafico vacio.**

[image: grafico]

Este es mi controlador ReportController **con este metodo public function getChart() realizo mi consulta**

```
public function getChart(Request $request)
    {      
        $_orders = DB::table('users')
            ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')                        
            ->select('users.id','users.name', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.id) as orders_by_user'), 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')                   
            ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2');
        $_orders->groupBy('orders.user_id', 'users.id',  'users.name',  'model_has_roles.role_id');
        $orders=$_orders->get();

        return ['orders' => $orders];

    }
```

Este es el resultado de mi consulta: como se observa tengo lo que necesito nombre de usuario y la cantidad de ordenes terminadas por usuario.

```
{
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"orders_by_user": 2,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Jose",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Miguel",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
}
]
}
```

**Mi problema esta en mi metodo function getChartData() que es el metodo donde realizo mi llamada ajax o esta en el metodo function renderChart(data, labels) que es el metodo que utilizo para realizar el grafico con los datos obtenidos?.**

Este es mi archivo report.js  para el grafico:

```
function renderChart(data, labels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'ordenes',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                borderWidth: 1,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true                        
                    }
                }]
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Ordenes en estado terminado"
            },
        }
    });
}



function getChartData() {   

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/reports/getChart',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

           // console.log(data);
            var data = [];
            var labels = [];



            for (var i in data) {
                data.push(data[i].orders_by_user);
                labels.push(data[i].name);

            }

            renderChart(data, labels);
        },
        error: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$("#renderBtn").click(
    function () {
        getChartData();
    }
);
```

¿Podrian ayudarme a encontrar y dar solucion a  mi error?

Comment: Te general algún error? tengo un ejemplo muy parecido, se me ocurre que probablemente el problema esta en el archivo donde crear el JSON, es decir la estructura del archivo JSON, en mi caso yo declaro un arreglo llamado data = [ "labels" => $label, "values" => 2]; este arreglo se lo paso con array_push al arreglo principal array_push($response, $data) para después imprimirlo de la siguiente manera echo json_encode($response) quedando la siguiente estructura [{"labels":"label1","values":"2"},{},{}],  si gustas te puedo comentar un respuesta completa con mi ejemplo saludos

Comment: @luis_am92 de todas maneras he actualizado mi pregunta he agregado mi metodo getChart() en el cual realizo mi consulta puedes revisarlo como puedo pasar una estructura correcta del archivo JSON?.

Comment: @luis_am92 por favor me puedes pasar tu respuesta completa, asi puedo observar como pasas la estructura JSON., Además creo que mi llamada Ajax no es del todo correcta

Comment: Claro dame unos minutos y te la paso.

Comment: @luis_am92  Si estare atento a su respuesta.

Comment: Amigo, lo haz logrado solucionar?

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, la pregunta es antigua pero para quienes tengan este mismo problema, se debe a la forma en que se recorre el JSON y en el uso de variables ambiguas.

A continuación dejo el código para que ejecutes y revises

```js
$('button')
  .html('Ejecutar') // texto en el boton...
  .on('click', ()=>{
    console.log('le di click al boton');

    //simular el envio de datos con funcionDeAjax

    funcionDelAjax(datosDeEntrada);           //funcion original
    funcionCorregidaDelAjax(datosDeEntrada);  // funcion nueva
  });

var datosDeEntrada = {
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Luis",
      "orders_by_user": 2,
      "rol": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Jose",
      "orders_by_user": 1,
      "rol": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Miguel",
      "orders_by_user": 1,
      "rol": 2
    }
  ]
  };

function funcionDelAjax(data) {
  // console.log(data);
  var data = [];
  var labels = [];

  for (var item of data) {
      data.push(item.orders_by_user);
      labels.push(item.name);
  }

  console.log('data final -> ', data);
  console.log('label final -> ', labels);
  //renderChart(data, labels);
  
};
function funcionCorregidaDelAjax(dataEntrante) {

  var data = [];
  var labels = [];

  var dataForof = []
  var labelsForOf =[]
  /**
   * 1. Debes usar nombre de variables diferentes si son locales. ejemplo(data != dataEntrante)
   * 2. Debes recorrer el json de forma correcta
   * 2.1. ingresa a la key "orders" de tu json
   * 
   */
 
 //utilizando for in
  for (var i in dataEntrante['orders']) {
      data.push(dataEntrante['orders'][i].orders_by_user);
      labels.push(dataEntrante['orders'][i].name);

  }

  //utilizando for of
  for (var item of dataEntrante['orders']) {
      dataForof.push(item.orders_by_user);
      labelsForOf.push(item.name);

  }
  console.log('data final mejorado-> ', data);
  console.log('label final mejorado-> ', labels);
  console.log('-----------------------------')
  console.log('data final mejorado forOf -> ', dataForof);
  console.log('label final mejorado forOf -> ', labelsForOf);

  //renderChart(data, labels);

};
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button></button>
```